# Adding non-filetype in shell new context menu in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

I've already known how to add specific extension to the New Menu in Windows 7 with regedit, but now I want to add the type FILE (i.e. **pure file without an extension**), how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I got it right with google. Here is the solution: 
1. Create a key of any extension or just a '.' in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and make the default value 'genericfile'

2. Create the ShellNew in the extension you just created

3.Create a string in the ShellNew with the name 'NullFile' and the value empty

4.Create the key 'Config' in the 'ShellNew' and a string in the config with the name 'NoExtension' and value empty

5.Create the key 'genericfile' in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and make the default value the text you want to display in your new context value (Such as "New Empty File")

Wish helps you a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a registry script based on lichenbo's answer.

It uses `.emptyfile` to avoid conflicts. Using `.` registry key could cause strange issues. The file will still be created with no extension due to the `NoExtension` value.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emptyfile]
@="Empty File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.emptyfile]
@="emptyfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.emptyfile\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.emptyfile\ShellNew\config]
"NoExtension"=""
```